# yii2 rewrite rule for customer portal

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have an yii advanced app with frontend and backend.

What I try to achieve is that I can access the frontend with the name of a customer.

Example (local): `http://localhost/myproject/frontend/web/customer1` should become `http://localhost/myproject/frontend/web/customer1/site/login` at first visit

And after login the name of the customer should stay in the URL. At the moment the URL changes after login to `http://localhost/myproject/frontend/web/`

Info:
`customer` is a GET parameter. It should always be the first argument after `http://localhost/myproject/frontend/web/` but I don't want to specify the argument in each redirect or custom link. I hope there's a way to keep this argument and pass it to each of the following site changes.

What I have tried so far:

```
'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true, 
            'rules' => [
                '<controller>/<action>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<customer:\w+>' => '/site/login',
            ]
        ],
```

But this is not working. I can only access the login page and afterwards the customer name is not showing anymore in the URL.

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

I'm really appreciate any hints on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prepend customer name to all urls modify your url rule:

```
<customer:\w+>/<controller>/<action>' => '<controller>/<action>,
```

If you now call `yii\helpers\Url::to(['site/index', 'customer' => 'customer'])`the output will be as you want - `/customer/site/index`.

Howewer calling it like that in entire project is not flexible approach.

Most of the times `Url::to()` method is used for generating internal urls.

If you pass array in `$route`, it will call `Url::toRoute()`. So you can simply override that method in your custom component.

```
namespace frontend\components;

use yii\helpers\Url as BaseUrl;

class Url extends BaseUrl
{
    public static function toRoute($route, $scheme = false)
    {
        $customer = ... // Get saved after login customer name (for example from the session)
        $route['customer'] = $customer;

        return parent::toRoute($route, $scheme);
    }
}
```

Then you can simply call `frontend\components\Url::to(['site/index'])` to achieve the same result.

Alternative way of customizing helper classes described in official documentation [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-overview.html#customizing-helper-classes).

**Update:**

Also this url rule `'<customer:\w+>' => '/site/login',` is redundant and the url should be just `site/login`, because any user before signing in is guest.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to handle $this->goBack() and $this->goHome(). They seem to use Url::to() whitout using an array as parameter. Is there a simple way to also overwrite Url::to() and set my GET parameter?

Comment: You can try to specify your custom class in `Yii::$classMap`. See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-overview.html#customizing-helper-classes. I already mentioned that in the answer.

Comment: Yes, I did this method for Url::toRoute(). But I trouble with Url::to(). I know I can also overwrite this method in my class but I do not already know how to set my GET parameter there.

Comment: As I said in case of passing array `Url::to()` will call `Url::toRoute()` method at the very beginning (https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/helpers/BaseUrl.php#L202). So overriding `Url::toRoute()` for most of the cases should be enough.

Comment: If you want, you can change `Url::to()` method in proper place or even main method `createUrl()` in `yii\web\UrlManager` class.

Comment: Yes, but only when Url::to()'s parameter is an array. I think that eg. $this->GoBack() passes a string to Url::to() and therefore my customized toRoute() function is not called.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69588/discussion-between-arogachev-and-sarah-west).